# Determine the angle of 3 drawn lines from each corner of 3 congruent squares

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

Three squares are drawn next to each other. Three lines are drawn from a corner as illustrated. Determine the sum of the three angles exposed (the exact number of degrees or radians):

[image]

Comment: Do you know about trigonometry, like tangents and stuff?

Comment: Yes. Try do derive me to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
 $$\tan \alpha_1=1 \qquad \tan \alpha_2=\frac{1}{2} \qquad \tan \alpha_3=\frac{1}{3}$$

and
$$
\tan (\alpha_1+\alpha_2)=\frac{\tan \alpha_1+\tan \alpha_2}{1-\tan \alpha_2\tan \alpha_2}=\frac{1+1/2}{1-1/2}=3
$$
so: $$\tan (\alpha_1+\alpha_2)=\frac{1}{\tan \alpha_3}$$
and this means that $\alpha_3$ is the complement of $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, i.e. $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=90°$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Draw another one-by-two domino, but aligned at $45$ degrees to this one, whose lower-left and upper-right corners are the upper-left and lower-right corners of the original diagram. You will find that the proposition becomes self evident.

(When I get to a console, I'll draw it out if that helps.)  Martin Gardner fans should recognize it.